# 1D representation of 2D discrete Fourier transformation

Tags: fourier-transform, visualization, image-processing

I'm not too familiar with image processing, so I need a little help:
In general, if we transform a discrete function $f$ with $n$-variables from the "spatial domain" using the Fourier transformation, then there are also $n$-variables (frequencies) in the "frequency domain". So an image, which appears obviously 2D ($xy$-plane) leads then into a 2D contour plot if one plots the amplitude and phase spectrum.

I found an interesting work [1] about saliency maps, where the authors used "orientation averaged curves of $\log$ spectra":

Is someone fimiliar with this terminology?
Is this just the averaging of row entries for each column?

I found nowhere else this 1D representation of an actual 2D plot.

Best regards,
Albert

**Reference**

[1] X. Hou and L. Zhang, "[Saliency Detection: A Spectral Residual Approach](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4270292)", *2007 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition*, Minneapolis, MN, USA, 2007, pp. 1-8, doi: 10.1109/CVPR.2007.383267.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question will likely get better answer/response on dsp.stackexchange.com